# ORA-01446: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ora-01446

Just trying to insert a Row in the Customer table which is not included in the Error Table.

--View

```
Create View A3_SRC_CUST_VIEW As
Select SRC_CUST_A.*, rowid as row_id From SRC_CUST_A
Union All
Select SRC_CUST_B.*, rowid as row_id From SRC_CUST_B;
```

-- Insert Statement

```
Insert Customer (DW_CUST_ID, CUSTID, CUSTNAME, CUSTEMAIL, CUSTLOC)
Select  Dw_Cust_Id.Nextval,  v.CID,  v.NAME, v.Email, v.LOC
From CustView v
Where v.rowid Not In
    (Select Source_RowId From A3_Error_Event  Where Filter_Id = 4 );
```

The error I am getting is *ORA-01446: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.
01446. 00000 -  "cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting rowid instead of row_id from the view.This causes the error.